# Access a nested structure by path (i.e., "Model.NestedModel.ListOfThings[1]")

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, nested

Given the following classes and data:

```
public class InnerExample
{
    public string Inner1 { get; set; }
}


public class Example
{
    public string Property1 { get; set; }
    public string Property2 { get; set; }
    public List<InnerExample> Inner { get; set; }
}

var a = new Example
{
    Property1 = "Foo",
    Property2 = "Bar",
    Inner = new List<InnerExample>
    {
      new InnerExample
      {
        Inner1 = "This is the value to change"
      }
   }
};
```

Is there any way to access the innermost data by path?

Is there any way to say...

```
a["Inner[0].Inner1"] = "New value"
```

In this particular case, I know for a fact that I will never be accessing a key that does not exist, so I'm not overly concerned about error checking.

(Sorry if this has been asked before.  I did a few searches but quickly ran out of keywords to try.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the basic advice you gave me, Jon, I came up with a solution that works for my case.

- There is **no** error checking
- You must be setting a property, not an array element.
- I'm sure there are more efficient ways to do this... I'm far from an expert on reflection.

  ```
  /// <summary>
  /// Take an extended key and walk through an object to update it.
  /// </summary>
  /// <param name="o">The object to update</param>
  /// <param name="key">The key in the form of "NestedThing.List[2].key"</param>
  /// <param name="value">The value to update to</param>
  private static void UpdateModel(object o, string key, object value)
  {
      // TODO:
      // Make the code more efficient.

      var target = o;
      PropertyInfo pi = null;

      // Split the key into bits.
      var steps = key.Split('.').ToList();

      // Don't walk all the way to the end
      // Save that for the last step.
      var lastStep = steps[steps.Count-1];
      steps.RemoveAt(steps.Count-1);

      // Step through the bits.
      foreach (var bit in steps)
      {
          var step = bit;

          string index = null;

          // Is this an indexed property?
          if (step.EndsWith("]"))
          {
              // Extract out the value of the index
              var end = step.IndexOf("[", System.StringComparison.Ordinal);
              index = step.Substring(end+1, step.Length - end - 2);

              // and trim 'step' back down to exclude it.  (List[5] becomes List)
              step = step.Substring(0, end);
          }

          // Get the new target.
          pi = target.GetType().GetProperty(step);
          target = pi.GetValue(target);

          // If the target had an index, find it now.
          if (index != null)
          {
              var idx = Convert.ToInt16(index);

              // The most generic way to handle it.
              var list = (IEnumerable) target;
              foreach (var e in list)
              {
                  if (idx ==0)
                  {
                      target = e;
                      break;
                  }
                  idx--;
              }
          }
      }

      // Now at the end we can apply the last step,
      // actually setting the new value.
      if (pi != null || steps.Count == 0)
      {
          pi = target.GetType().GetProperty(lastStep);
          pi.SetValue(target, value);
      }
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing built-in, but it's possible to do (even though it won't be trivial).

What you want is to add an [indexer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/6x16t2tx.aspx) to the class `Example`. Inside the indexer you will have to parse the provided "property path" into steps and use [reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7ykdhsy.aspx) to resolve the target property step by step.

For example, after parsing `Inner[0].Inner1` into three distinct steps (fetch `Inner`, then from that fetch `[0]`, then from that `Inner1`) you would have a loop that goes somewhat like this:

```
// This works only with plain (non-indexed) properties, no error checking, etc.
object target = this;
PropertyInfo pi = null;
foreach (var step in steps)
{
    pi = target.GetType().GetProperty(step);
    target = pi.GetValue(target);
}

// And now you can either return target (on a get) or use pi.SetValue (on a set)
```

Comment: Thank you.  That got me on the road to my own solution which I have posted here.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a cleaner version I made. It is slightly faster using Stopwatch to get the time. Sometimes it is 30ms quicker.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Sets the nested property value.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="obj">The object.</param>
    /// <param name="path">The path.</param>
    /// <param name="value">The value.</param>
    /// <exception cref="System.ArgumentException">Invalid list index or property '{propertyName}' not found in type '{currentObject.GetType().FullName}'</exception>
    /// <exception cref="System.ArgumentException">Property '{properties[^1]}' not found in type '{currentObject.GetType().FullName}'.</exception>
    /// <exception cref="System.ArgumentException">Invalid list index '{index}' in the final step.</exception>
    /// <exception cref="System.ArgumentException">Property '{properties[^1]}' not found in type '{currentObject.GetType().FullName}'.</exception>
    public static void SetNestedPropertyValue(object obj, string path, object value) {
        string[] properties = path.Split('.');
        object currentObject = obj;

        int index = -1;

        // Traverse the property path.
        for (int i = 0; i < properties.Length - 1; i++) {
            if (TryGetPropertyNameAndIndex(properties[i], out string propertyName, out index)) {
                var list = currentObject.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName)?.GetValue(currentObject) as System.Collections.IList;
                if (list == null || index < 0 || index >= list.Count) {
                    throw new ArgumentException($"Invalid list index or property '{propertyName}' not found in type '{currentObject.GetType().FullName}'");
                }

                currentObject = list[index];
            } else {
                PropertyInfo propertyInfo = currentObject.GetType().GetProperty(properties[i]);

                if (propertyInfo is null) {
                    throw new ArgumentException($"Property '{properties[i]}' not found in type '{currentObject.GetType().FullName}'.");
                }

                currentObject = propertyInfo.GetValue(currentObject);
            }
        }

        if (currentObject is IList<object> finalList) {
            if (index < 0 || index >= finalList.Count) {
                throw new ArgumentException($"Invalid list index '{index}' in the final step.");
            }

            finalList[index] = value;
        } else {
            PropertyInfo finalProperty = currentObject.GetType().GetProperty(properties[properties.Length - 1]);

            if (finalProperty is null) {
                throw new ArgumentException($"Property '{properties[properties.Length - 1]}' not found in type '{currentObject.GetType().FullName}'.");
            }

            finalProperty.SetValue(currentObject, value);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Tries to get the index of the get property if it is a list object.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="property">The property path.</param>
    /// <param name="propertyName">Name of the final property.</param>
    /// <param name="index">The index of the property list object.</param>
    /// <returns><c>true</c> if the property is a <see cref="System.Collections.IList"/> , <c>false</c> otherwise.</returns>
    /// <exception cref="System.ArgumentException">Invalid list index in property '{property}'.</exception>
    public static bool TryGetPropertyNameAndIndex(string property, out string propertyName, out int index) {
        propertyName = property;
        index = -1;

        int startIndex = property.IndexOf('[');
        int endIndex = property.IndexOf(']');

        if (startIndex != -1 && endIndex != -1) {
            propertyName = property.Substring(0, startIndex);

            if (!int.TryParse(property.Substring(startIndex + 1, endIndex - startIndex - 1), out index)) {
                throw new ArgumentException($"Invalid list index in property '{property}'.");
            }
        }

        return startIndex != -1 && endIndex != -1;
    }
```

Test code:

```
   Stopwatch timer = new Stopwatch();
    timer.Start();
    UpdateModel(someObjectInstance, error.PropertyName, "test");
    timer.Stop();
    Debug.WriteLine("Time Taken: " + timer.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds.ToString("#,##0.00 'milliseconds'"));

    timer = new Stopwatch();
    timer.Start();

    GetNestedPropertyValue(someObjectInstance, error.PropertyName, "test");
    timer.Stop();
    Debug.WriteLine("Time Taken: " + timer.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds.ToString("#,##0.00 'milliseconds'"));
```